# navigator.app.exitApp() crashes on phonegap 3.1.0

Tags: android, cordova

Everytime navigator.app.exitApp()  is called in my app ,the App is crashing.Kindly find below the crash log that I get.

```
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to       destroy activity {com.pixatel.mathwhiz/com.pixatel.mathwhiz.MathWhiz}:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: null
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3312)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:138)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: null
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:654)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1165)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:378)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at org.apache.cordova.device.Device.onDestroy(Device.java:98)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.onDestroy(PluginManager.java:326)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.handleDestroy(CordovaWebView.java:833)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onDestroy(CordovaActivity.java:774)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5172)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1109)
01-09 13:20:24.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3281)
```

The Code below is my main activity file :-

```
public class MathWhiz extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());

        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index_android.html");

        try {
            String pName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
            this.copy("Databases.db", "/data/data/" + pName + "/app_database/");
            this.copy("0000000000000001.db", "/data/data/" + pName
                    + "/app_database/file__0/");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       // super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index_android.html",3000);
    }

    void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException {

        File CheckDirectory;
        CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
        if (!CheckDirectory.exists()) {
            CheckDirectory.mkdir();
        }

        InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder + file);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        in.close();
        out.close();
```

This issue wasn't there in the phonegap version 2.9.0.Started happening with 3.1.0.
Please let me know what is the issue associated with it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any receiver in your MathWiz activity ? If so, then I guess that you are unregistering a null receiver reference in the onDestroy method of MathWiz activity.

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim : Hi I have updated the query with my main activity java file as well.Can you please check it and let me know what the issue is?

Comment: According to that [file](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-plugin-device.git;a=blob;f=src/android/Device.java;h=2ce3cc73dbc6df7d6b382c1cd8bde13b35ebced8;hb=2d0c783beea770d36d5df86d5e3e45039cd16876)
The Device plugin registers a receiver to listen for Telephony actions.
So are you sure that you have added the required permissions to make Telephony work in the Android.Manifest.xml file ?

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim : Thanks a lot,I checked my "device.java" file was incomplete.Please move your comment to "Answers" so that I can accept your answer.Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to that [file](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-plugin-device.git;a=blob;f=src/android/Device.java;h=2ce3cc73dbc6df7d6b382c1cd8bde13b35ebced8;hb=2d0c783beea770d36d5df86d5e3e45039cd16876) the Device plugin registers a receiver to listen for Telephony actions. So make sure that you have added the required permissions to make Telephony work in the Android.Manifest.xml file.

Comment: Just to add, the correct permissions should be `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`