# Phonegap 3.2.0 "Unfortunately, AppName has stopped." dialog when closing app

Tags: android, cordova

When I close my app, I get a dialog box saying "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped." and an OK button.  By closing, I mean pressing the back button from the first screen.  The app does close fine, but then this dialog appears a few seconds later.

I'm using PhoneGap 3.2.0.  It didn't happen prior to updating to 3.x.x. I'm not sure exactly which version after this is the culprit.

The LogCat in Eclipse puts out this when it happens:

```
01-13 15:20:42.764: D/CordovaActivity(32367): onMessage(exit,null)
01-13 15:20:42.829: D/CordovaActivity(32367): Paused the application!
01-13 15:20:42.839: W/PluginManager(32367): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to App.exitApp blocked the main thread for 74ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
01-13 15:20:43.219: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(32367): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-13 15:20:43.254: D/CordovaActivity(32367): CordovaActivity.onDestroy()
01-13 15:20:43.259: D/CordovaWebView(32367): >>> loadUrlNow()
01-13 15:20:43.284: D/AndroidRuntime(32367): Shutting down VM
01-13 15:20:43.284: W/dalvikvm(32367): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417752a0)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {MyAppName}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: null
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3314)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3332)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:140) 
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: null
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:654)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1277)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:385)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at org.apache.cordova.device.Device.onDestroy(Device.java:98)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.onDestroy(PluginManager.java:332)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.handleDestroy(CordovaWebView.java:833)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onDestroy(CordovaActivity.java:774)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5370)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1113)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3301)
01-13 09:56:40.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13858):    ... 11 more
```

Any ideas?

Until now, I've always been using the line
navigator.app.exitApp();
to close the app if I detect that I'm on the index.html page when the back button is pressed.

I tried instead to remove the backbutton listener and restore the default behaviour when the back button was pressed.  It still results in the same problem.

Here's some shortened code snippets:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady()
{
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButton, false);
});

function backButton()
{
    var currentLocation = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    switch (currentLocation) {
    case 'index.html':
    navigator.app.exitApp();
    break;
}
```

**Update 2014/01/13 16:00:**
Not sure if it is any help, but I've noticed that it doesn't give any errors if I comment out the script src="cordova.js" from index.html.

Comment: Please share your main code.

Comment: Here is another user, was facing the same problem as yours
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014752/navigator-app-exitapp-crashes-on-phonegap-3-1-0/21016695#21016695

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file Device.java replace the content of `OnDestroy` with this

```
if( this.telephonyReceiver != null )
   this.cordova.getActivity().unregisterReceiver(this.telephonyReceiver);
```

**Warning:** This is hiding the original problem where the BroadcastReceiver isn't being registered properly from what I got from the logcat. Adding the permission to the `AndroidManifest.xml` like [suprnova](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21090361/1495263) said should've worked.

But if you don't need to know the phone state, ie, if you're getting a call, or something like that, and you need a quick fix.

**Warning 2:** When the next phonegap version comes out, this may get overridden.

Comment: I am using cordova -version 3.3.1-0.1.2 and still found this problem. Your answer help me, thanks.

Comment: where is Device.java?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your LogCat, the problem lies in the `Device.java` file, and looking at the source [here](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-plugin-device.git;a=blob;f=src/android/Device.java;h=2ce3cc73dbc6df7d6b382c1cd8bde13b35ebced8;hb=2d0c783beea770d36d5df86d5e3e45039cd16876), the class registers a `BroadcastReceiver` to check the phone state.

Make sure you have added:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`

to your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I've given this a try.  No change I'm afraid.  I did come across the same link when I was searching for the answer too.